# When selecting an item the header should not change

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu

I have this script (I'm new to this, so I'm not very familiar with the terminology). **Feel free to edit the question** if you can rephrase it in a better way.

```
<script>
            var counter=0;
            var oldJSON = null;

            setInterval(function() { 
                    var mycounter=0;
                    $.getJSON('mydata.json', function(data) { 
                            if(JSON.stringify(oldJSON) != JSON.stringify(data)){ 
                                $("#notifications").html("");
                                $("#notifications").append("<option style=display:none></option>")
                                $.each(data.items, function(i, v) {
                                        counter= counter + 1;  
                                        document.getElementById('test').innerHTML=counter ;
                                        $('#notifications').append('<option value="' + v.type + '">' + v.type +"->"+ v.text +"->"+v.pnr+ '</option>');

                                        ;});
                            }
                            oldJSON = data;

                    }); 
                },2000);

        </script>
```

It takes the **data** from a JSON file and appends it to `#notifications` which is a dropdown element.

What I'm trying to create is a Facebook type notification dropdown.

This is my html:

```
<div class="hello">
        <select id="notifications" style="background-image:url(live_data.jpg);" ></select>
        </div>
    <div id="test" style="color:red;margin-left:90px;font-size: 15px;font-family: arial;"></div>
```

Now, as you may have seen, I appended a blank item to the dropdown so that the old data gets cleared out.

**Now here lies the problem**: when I clear this data, the first element comes onto the image(overlaps). I added a empty item for it(not a very good way, I know... here also suggestions are welcome). But the thing is when I select any of them it overlaps onto the image.

Any help or advice would do... thanks in advance.

I'm **open to suggestions** if there is any other way to do it

Comment: By adding a background-image to your select tag, the selected option will by default "overlap" over the image since the select tag always picks the value of the option that has been selected. If one has not yet been selected it picks the value of the first option. The question is do you need the background-image?

Comment: actually i do,that's why i mentioned in the question.. _facebook_ like dropdown

Comment: I'm open to suggestions if there is any other way to do it

Comment: I think you need to look at custom drop down menus as an alternative to using the select tag. Try this tutorial for help http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/10/04/custom-drop-down-list-styling/

Comment: actually i did try all of those,what i needed was a little bit like the 4th Demo...but i wasn't able to implement it as I'm new to `html css` & `javascript`

Comment: What does the live_data.jpg image look like?

Comment: Like [this](http://imgur.com/3PIpt07)

Comment: Does this (http://projects.amurani.net/dropdown/) help?

Comment: really thanks for trying to help me out. unfortunately the icon is a part of webpage which doesn't have that much space...but still thanks a lot,I'm now trying again on the previous link that you provided